# Opening a project in xCode from working app deployed to dev phone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm a reasonably new iOS developer, still on the steep part of the learning curve.

Late last year I finished an app and had it running successfully on my old iPhone 4. I subsequently upgraded xCode etc to work with iPhone 5, after not touching the project for a couple of months.

Some how, something has gone wrong with my app in xCode. I continually get crashes at launch, and have tried everything I can think of (and search for) to resolve.

What I would like to do is open the project in xCode from the working app on the 4, as I know it works. Is it possible??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: You cannot take an app from iPhone and run in Xcode. If you have the source code for that you can run that in your Xcode.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your replies. I started by checking all of the connections in the NIB, re-wrote the launch view controller, & pointed the app delegate to another view controller (which worked). Not to worry, I suspected it was not possible.

Comment: Without seeing some of the error msgs how can anyone help you?

Comment: skinnyTOD - thanks - I was not after help about the cause of the crashes, just wanted to know if I could open a project from my app running on the old phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot take an app from iPhone and run in Xcode. If you have the source code which was used to build that app, you can use it to run in your Xcode. Once you have installed an app in iPhone, you cannot convert it to back to the source code in normal ways or using Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. After closing xCode, reopening, changing project name, and some other random things it seems to have come right.